# Change foreign key in Laravel core tables

Tags: laravel, migration, jobs, laravel-6

I created a job table in Laravel with the following database schema.

```php
Schema::create('jobs', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->bigIncrements('job_id');
    $table->string('queue')->index();
    $table->longText('payload');
    $table->unsignedTinyInteger('attempts');
    $table->unsignedInteger('reserved_at')->nullable();
    $table->unsignedInteger('available_at');
    $table->unsignedInteger('created_at');
});
```

This does not work, however when I change the primary key `job_id` to `id` it works. How can I customize this?

Answer (score 1):

Edit your model, you must define `$primaryKey` in your model:

```
protected $primaryKey = 'job_id';
```

Comment: I have no modal for job table, if i create a modal for this how to link with this...this table is created by laravel migration php artisan queue:table

Comment: Create a model with name `Job`. This model auto found `jobs` table but your table name is `job`. You must define your table name again in your model as `protected $table = 'job';` and please use your model for crud actions.